# Rejected from ThreadPoolExecutor, multiple bound services

Tags: java, android, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor, java-threads

In a FOR loop within one of my bound services, I make another call to another bound service. I get the error `"rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor"`. I know this is because there are not enough threads to execute my tasks. I'm a bit confused regarding thread pools but I know I need something like this to make the threads wait.

How can I make the messages wait (below) for a free thread before sending a message to the service?

```
Message message = Message.obtain(null, TwitterService.REQUEST, 0, 0);
SendFBIDParcel parcel = new SendFBIDParcel();
parcel.id = item.getGivenID();

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("id", parcel);
message.setData(bundle);

try {
   messenger.send(message);
   counter++;
} catch (RemoteException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Where did you get `messenger` from? Can you influence its configuration?

Comment: sorry I don't understand, messenger is what I use to send a message to the service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `AsyncTask`to perform it.

Check : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

There's an example here: http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-asynctask-example/

You've got this message beacuse you have exceeded the number of tasks for the `ThreadPoolExecutor`

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm using the bound service to send a request and wait to retrieve a response - will the async task wait for the response before making the next request?

Comment: @NataliaSharon Yes, you can set a Timeout.

Comment: doesn't that kill the thread after a certain period of time, rather than waiting for the network response before executing the next task?